# Creating Date objects from date string query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

So I have an action that accepts an ISO 8601 string through query parameter `fromDate`.
An example GET request (encoded) to this action would be as such
`http://localhost:1337/createFromDate?fromDate='2016-05-24T04%3A18%3A38.000Z'`

The issue I notice is when initializing the Date object with the fromDate parameter, an Invalid Date is returned. However, when I hardcode the same exact string, it creates the Date object with no problem.

The server-side code looks like this:

```
createFromDate: function(req,res){

    console.log(new Date(req.query.fromDate));
    // Invalid Date

    console.log(new Date('2016-05-24T04:18:38.000Z'));
    // Mon May 23 2016 21:18:38 GMT-0700 (PDT)

    res.ok()
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `req.query.fromDate`?

Comment: And why are there single quotes around the value?

Comment: @AtesGoral '2016-05-24T04:18:38.000Z'

Comment: You're not supposed to have the single quotes in the query string. Also, the ':' don't need to be encoded as '%3A' in the query portion of a URL. Just try: `http://localhost:1337/createFromDate?fromDate=2016-05-24T04:18:38.000Z`

Comment: Wow, thank you @AtesGoral. Did not realize that...

Comment: Hint: There's a difference between `encodeURIComponent` and `encodeURI`

Comment: Haha yea completely missed the fact I was passing those single quotes as part of the parameter. Thanks again @AtesGoral.